# How to simulate in blender, smoke coming out from a bottle or a flask?

Tags: smoke-simulation, fluid-simulation, fire

I want to create in blender an animation. It is possible to simulate the smoke that coming out from a bottle? I attached here my blend file.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1rL1v4v-wRPMsXDcpcNEVVpQGlpT3-nak

https://c8.alamy.com/comp/AP78GM/science-research-chemistry-flask-with-blue-solution-and-smoke-in-laboratory-AP78GM.jpg

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Make the Flow object bigger and put above the glass and invert the gravity so the smoke will also flow inside and outside the bottle. May be you have to increase the smoke resolution or subdivison (in the domian) for a better result. Unfortunatelly EEVEE doesn't support hollow glass objectives, so you have to use cycles rendering to see what's inside the bottle.(If you choose cycles I recommend the 2.79 version because it's more stable). Or you can also make thicker smoke to cover those details.
I recommend a hdri for background what you can download here:
https://hdrihaven.com/hdris/
If you use hdris you dont have to use lights.

Edit:
I made a test scene:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Vksf8SVzUqXFqZcXheBDsJNDx1mamO4M
Don't forget to bake the smoke.
Enjoy!